# Unexpected value when referencing a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm playing with [OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) compiler in order to understand how pointers work in C.
First, I ran the following code and got the output I expected:

```
int *array1[] = {1,4,3,4};

int main()
{
    printf("%d \n", array1[0+1]);
    printf("%d", array1[1+1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output was:
4
3

Secondly, I ran the following code - And I can't understand its output:

```
int *array1[] = {1,4,3,4};

int main()
{
    printf("%d \n", array1[0]+1);
    printf("%d", array1[1]+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
5
8

It seems like I'm adding 4 to the value from the array, but why? (each element in the array is consisted from a byte).

Thanks!

Comment: Note that printing pointers (your array elements are pointers) with `"%d"` is not correct and invokes UB.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems like I'm adding 4 to the value from the array, but why?

No, each element of the array is an `int *` because you declared the array that way:

```
int *array1[] = {1,4,3,4};
```

That says `array1` is an array whose values have type pointer to `int`. Remove the `*` if you want an array of `int`, like:

```
int array1[] = {1,4,3,4};
```

When you add or subtract from pointer types, the value changes by some multiple of the size of the type that the pointer refers to. An `int` on your system is probably 4 bytes, so an expression like `array1[0]+1` gets the `int *` stored in `array[0]` and increments it, so it increases by `sizeof(int)`.

> (each element in the array is consisted from a byte).

Even if you had declared your array as an array of `int` rather than an array of `int *`, the *size* of an `int` is probably *not* 1 byte. `int` is typically 4 bytes long, but size depends on the compiler and target system.

Comment: Thanks, working. However, Can you explain my output in the second code?

Comment: @Bob_Bobb See the paragraph I just added, which I think explains it. Note that `1` or `4` are valid values for an `int *` even if there aren't actually `int` values stored at memory locations `1` or `4`.

Comment: Whether 1 and 4 are valid values for an `int *` is implementation-dependent. And it should be noted that the behavior upon attempting to print an `int *` using `%d` is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
int *array1[] = {1,4,3,4};
```

you are defining tan array of *pointers to integers*.

So every element of that array, even if initialized with what appear to be integer values, are actually *pointers*, that are addresses.

If you had deferenced those pointers you would probably have caused a segmentation fault. But fortunately you simply printed them, even if using `%d` instead of `%p`: a choice that according to C standard could have caused undefined behavior. Anyway in your case the pointers were converted to integers, and the printed values were the expected ones. Exactly like if the array was an array of *integers*.

In the second example you pushed it further: **you added 1 to the array elements**. But since they are pointers, then **pointers arithmetics** is applied. Meaning that ***pointer + N = pointer  + N * sizeof(*pointer)***. In this case, since `sizeof(int)` is 4:

> `array[0] + 1` =
>
> = `1 + sizeof (array[0])` =
>
> = `1 + sizeof( int )` =
>
> = `1 + 4` = **`5`**